# Is there a word which means that a subject is poignant or very relevant to the current discussion?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was having a discussion with someone who always brings up "Jumping the shark" whenever we discuss TV programs that have run, or are in danger of running too long.

When I asked them about this they said "Well, it a very good example of something that is very relevant to my point"

And I said "There should be a word for that". What's that word?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'm afraid I don't really understand your example about the shark. But how about the word *salient*, which means "poignant and relevant"? Felicitously, it also includes a connotation of "jumping", for it is derived of Latin *saliens* "jumping", from *salire* "to jump".

Comment: I would agree with the self-censoring author: the word is "apt."

Comment: The usual meaning of the word "poignant" is something like (quoting the online OED) "arousing or expressing deep emotion, esp. of sorrow or regret." I think you are using the word to mean something else, but I'm not sure exactly what. Or maybe "poignant" was a spellcheck error and you meant to type some other word?

Comment: I would advise you to look at the "synonym discussion of *apposite*" on Merriam-Webster. (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apposite)

Comment: @bof I suspect they were shooting for 'pertinent'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the few potential words:

## **Apposite** (adjective)

*NOTE:* this word looks very similar to **opposite**.

[OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/apposite) describes it as:

> **Apt in the circumstances or in relation to something.**
>
> > "It is an **apposite** example, without being the most obvious."

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Apposite) describes it as:

> **highly pertinent or appropriate : apt**
>
> > **apposite** remarks or **apposite** examples

## **Germane** (adjective):

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/germane) describes it as:

> **being at once relevant and appropriate: *fitting***
>
> > "omit details that are not **germane** to the"**

[OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/germane) describes it as:  describes it as:

> **Relevant to a subject under consideration.**
>
> > that is **germane** point to our discussion

Comment: Thanks to all contributors, I think given my specific needs, a one-word probably wouldn't do the conversation justice. Whilst apropos is nice to say, there seems to be an element of "aptness" about it. Instead, i'll opt for "There's your go-to germane discussion point again". Thanks all.

Answer (score 4):

Used as an adjective the word apropos would fit.

> adjective
>       1   1.  >very appropriate to a particular situation."the composer's reference to child's play is apropos"
>       2   synonyms:
>       3   appropriate, pertinent, relevant, >apposite, apt, applicable, suitable, germane, fitting, befitting, material; right on "the word “conglomerate” was decidedly apropos"